# How to draw the outline of a thick line?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, graphics

I want to draw the outline of a thick line, that was drawn with a geometric pen. The line can be a polygon or a curve, but for simplicity I'm using a straight line.

[image]

Given two `POINT` variables A and B, the following code draws a black 16-pixel wide line with round endcaps between A and B:

```
LOGBRUSH lb = {BS_SOLID, clBlack, 0};

HPEN Pen = ExtCreatePen(PS_GEOMETRIC | PS_SOLID | PS_ENDCAP_ROUND, 16, &lb, 0, NULL);

HPEN OldPen = SelectObject(DC, Pen);

MoveToEx(DC, A.x, A.y, NULL);
LineTo  (DC, B.x, B.y);

SelectObject(DC, OldPen);
```

The idea was to place the above code between [`BeginPath(DC)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-beginpath) and `EndPath(DC)`, and use [`StrokePath(DC)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-strokepath) to draw the outline of the thick line, using a 1-pixel pen. But, instead of drawing the outline (the green line in the image), it draws a 1-pixel line between A and B (the red line in the image).

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I don't know if you can use it here, I know that one method of drawing outlines on 3D models, is to scale the model up by a few percent, draw it with all black textures, and then draw the model again on top, at normal scale with the correct textures. Perhaps you can draw a green 18 pixel thick line, and then draw a 16 pixel, background colored line on top?

Comment: @rustyx`WidenPath` after `EndPath` fixed it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`WidenPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-widenpath) after defining the path:

> The `WidenPath` function redefines the current path as the area that would be painted if the path were stroked using the pen currently selected into the given device context.